# Board to Board interfacing connectors

Tags: pcb

I'm in the process of designing a tiny embedded system, it has quite a bit
of sensors and it is controlled by 2 MCUs.

On previous versions of the test boards, I used 2mm pitch size headers for connecting the main board to a programming board. For the new version of the board, we definitely can not put these headers anymore.

[image: Figure]

I had the idea of using tiny 0.35 ~ 0.4 mm pitch connectors to interface both boards. I never tried to deal with this type of connectors before and I was wondering if they would be a good option for repetitive use,  which will happen when programming and testing the device.

I've found the processes of connector hunting quite hard as there is a HUGE selection of parts and I cannot find the wire that I'm looking for. I think I may have to custom order a FPC wire too?

I’m wondering if anyone had a similar experience or suggest a different method for interfacing the boards?

Thanks

Comment: "we definitely can not put these headers anymore". The reason for you saying this is probably the biggest factor in selecting a replacement.

Comment: VTC - Questions seeking advice and recommendations on specific parts are off topic here.

Comment: @MichaelKaras I don't think this question quite matches that description. The OP is not looking for *specific parts* but instead is asking about different *methods* to mount boards together (i.e. card-edge, square headers, FFC, etc).

Comment: If you are just hooking and unhooking up a programming and debugging connection then look at a product called TagConnect. No connector at all.....just some pads.

Comment: @DerStrom, You are right, I'm looking for the most space efficient way to interface the boards. Without making a mess!

Comment: @MichaelKaras, The idea was interface both boards and control which programming interface to use from the Debug board using switches. Tag-connect would make things a bit simpler and rid the use of the Debug board but would also add the cost of providing the Tag-connect to the S/W engineers

Comment: I think I would need to work with a small footprint connector on the application board and find a way to make a flat-type connector which can also be connected to the programming board. I will try to contact with manufacturers to see if they can give some advice.

Comment: Have you considered a card-edge connector? You'll have to extend the overall size of your board slightly so that you can turn it into contact tabs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to know if connectors are good for repetitive use, look at its specification : it generally specifies how many mating cycles the connector can support.

Regarding an alternative solution, you can also consider to create your own "testbench" using a "bed of nails".

Personnaly I did so using "spring probes".  I prepared the PCB with several test pads distributed on a 2.54mm grid.  That allowed me to solder the "spring probes" on a downsized standard PCB card board with standard 2.54mm pitch. I wired the probes to a more regular connector fitted on the same "test PCB"

Further, I designed and 3D printed a bench in which I slide (and fix) this "test PCB".  The board under test (design) is placed on the top.  Guides help me place it at the appropriate distance and position easily and I have a method to keep it in place.

The spring probes that I used can support one million cycles - way beyond my needs.  The test pads do not need to be through hole and do not need to be colocated - just at common distances if you want to build your test pcb by hand.

You can also draw your test PCB in a CAD tool and produce it like any other card - in that case you only need to make sure that the locations match.

By the way, the same system is used as a production bench where the PCB under test is kept into place by hand just for the time needed to produce the test report.

Comment: "spring probes" aka: "pogo pins"